# Add Mailchimp susbscriber through Firebase Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, mailchimp

**Scenario :**

- I'm trying to create a Firebase Function to add a subscriber to a Mailchimp list using the Mailchimp API but after three days of trying different methods I've had little luck.

**Currently my function resembles:**

```
exports.addSubscriber = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 const Mailchimp = require('mailchimp-api-v3')
 const mailchimp = new Mailchimp('MY_API_KEY');

 mailchimp.post('/lists/'MY_LIST_ID'/members', {
    "email_address": 'test@gmail.com',
    "status": 'pending'
 }).then(function(results) {
    console.log('added new user to mailchimp list');
 })
 .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
 })
 return null 
});
```

- When I try to trigger the function it results in a 'crash' with 
  **Error: Cannot find module 'mailchimp-api-v3'** in the logs.
- I've already ran npm install mailchimp-api-v3 in my local Firebase
  directory so the module should be available.

Where am I going wrong?
   Is there a simpler way to use the Mailchimp API with Javascript?

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run

```
npm install mailchimp-api-v3 --save
```

It seams the above package is missing.